# Semáforos en hilos no se comportan como esperaba, JAVA

Tags: java, hilos

Hace poco que he empezado a estudiar hilos y he creado un pequeño programa para entender como funcionan. El programa consiste en que un hilo va metiendo carácteres en un array (de como mucho 10 carácteres) mientras que otro hilo los va sacando.

Utilizando semáforos la lógica me dice que cuando los hilos acaben el array de carácteres estará vacio. El problema es que que el hilo del Main nunca consigue acabar de ejecutarse. Creo que se está produciendo un deadlock, ambos hilos se han quedado esperando o algo parecido.

La clase BolsaDeLetras es compartida y es donde se van añadiendo o quitando carácteres:

```
public class BolsaDeLetras {

    public char[] listaCaracteres = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    private int indiceSiguienteCaracter = 0;


    protected synchronized void añadirCaracter(char caracter) {

        if (!listaLlena()) {
            listaCaracteres[indiceSiguienteCaracter] = caracter;
            notify();

            indiceSiguienteCaracter++;

        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println("La lista está llena, toca esperar");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }


    protected synchronized void quitarCaracter() {

        if (!listaVacia()) {

            listaCaracteres[indiceSiguienteCaracter - 1] = 0;
            notify();

            indiceSiguienteCaracter--;

        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println("La lista está vacía, toca esperar");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


    /* Comprueba si la lista de carácteres está llena*/

    private synchronized boolean listaLlena() {
        if (indiceSiguienteCaracter == 10) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*
    Comprueba si la lista de carácteres está vacia
    */

    private synchronized boolean listaVacia() {
        if (indiceSiguienteCaracter == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


}
```

La clase ProductorDeLetras selecciona una letra al azar y la intenta insertar.

```
public class ProductorDeLetras implements Runnable {
    private String alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ";
    private BolsaDeLetras bolsaDeLetras;

    public ProductorDeLetras(BolsaDeLetras bolsaDeLetras) {
        this.bolsaDeLetras = bolsaDeLetras;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        char caracter;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            caracter = alfabeto.charAt((int) (Math.random() * 25));
            bolsaDeLetras.añadirCaracter(caracter);
        }

    }
}
```

La clase ConsumidorDeLetras hace lo contrario, intenta ir sacando letras.

```
public class ConsumidorDeLetras implements Runnable {
    private BolsaDeLetras bolsaDeLetras;

    public ConsumidorDeLetras(BolsaDeLetras bolsaDeLetras) {
        this.bolsaDeLetras = bolsaDeLetras;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bolsaDeLetras.quitarCaracter();
        }
    }
}
```

La clase ProgramaPrincipal crea los hilos y los ejecuta.

```
public class ProgramaPrincipal {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        BolsaDeLetras bolsaDeLetras = new BolsaDeLetras();
        ProductorDeLetras productorDeLetras = new ProductorDeLetras(bolsaDeLetras);
        ConsumidorDeLetras consumidorDeLetras = new ConsumidorDeLetras(bolsaDeLetras);

        Thread hilo1 = new Thread(productorDeLetras);
        Thread hilo2 = new Thread(consumidorDeLetras);

        hilo1.start();
        hilo2.start();

        hilo1.join(5000);
        hilo2.join(5000);

        System.out.println(bolsaDeLetras.listaCaracteres);

    }
}
```

Alguien me sabe decir que es lo que está pasando y porque? Como lo soluciono?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios posibles problemas con la implementación.

Ambos, productor y consumidor fallan al producir o consumir cuando la lista esta llena o vacia respectivamente, por lo que muy posiblemente no va a insertar los 20 elementos o no serán completamente removidos por el consumidor.

Por otra parte, el uso de wait() se recomienda que se haga dentro de un while verificando la condición de espera, ya que puede que se despierte el thread y aun no se cumpla la condición o que el thread se despierte solo, tal y como específica el api de java.

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

El código de inserción quedaría algo así:

```
protected synchronized void añadirCaracter(char caracter) {
    while (listaLlena()) {
        try {
            System.out.println("La lista está llena, toca esperar");
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    listaCaracteres[indiceSiguienteCaracter] = caracter;
    indiceSiguienteCaracter++;
    notify();
}
```